# Can files/directories deleted with rm be restored?

Tags: data-recovery, rm

Is it possible to restore files/directories which are deleted from terminal using `rm` and `rm -r`?. If a file is deleted from graphical interface, it could be restored from trash, but how do you restore a file if it is removed using the rm utility?.

Comment: for tools to recover deleted files (in any form), you can take a look at this question http://askubuntu.com/q/3883/

Comment: Don't use "rm" if you wish to restore the files in future .You can use "rm-trash" utility :  https://github.com/nateshmbhat/rm-trash

Answer (score 84):

To this end I use `trash-cli` package and the following alias in my `~/.bashrc`

```
alias rm=trash
```

And the `trash-cli` package can be installed by the followoing command: `sudo apt-get install trash-cli`.

The files you remove will be moved to trash, and you can see them in nautilus trashcan.

You can always access the real `rm` by using one of the following method:

```
command rm something
'rm' something
\rm something
```

There are also commands to access the trashcan from terminal, `trash-list`, `restore-trash` (or `trash-restore`), `trash-empty` installable from package trash-cli (then see their man pages).

Last note, it is not advisable to use such an alias for super-user, because it can interfere with system operations.

Comment: It is a work-around, but does not really answer the question.

Comment: I think the user also would to know if there is some method to achieve the same behavior from command line. If not, I am ready to remove my answer.

Comment: It's good. I have gained some knowledge.

Comment: `"it is not advisable to use such an alias for super-user"` can you explain this a bit more please? What kind of `system operations` could be affected and what might the negative consequences be?

Comment: > To this end I use trash-cli package and the following alias in my ~/.bashrc
> alias rm=trash 

// Be aware, that this will work for CURRENT user only. So, when such alias will be used in the scripts, additional attention is needed

Answer (score 32):

Deleting it from terminal deletes it permanently - recovery is very hard and sometimes impossible.

If your partition type is `ext3` (check it by using the `System->Administration->Disk Utility`), then take a look at [ext3undel](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/141074).

If it is not (if you installed Ubuntu with **default** settings), try the `extundelete` program.

There is no guarantee you will recover anything though.

Comment: It would be really useful for desktop editions.

Comment: I doubt this works effectively for SSD drives, but happy to hear otherwise

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for: **extundelete** - *utility to recover deleted files from ext3/ext4 partition*

To find such a package, you can try: `apt-cache search undelete`

To use the utility install it with: `sudo apt-get install extundelete`

After installation invoke [`man extundelete`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/extundelete.1.html) and study it carefully.

Answer (score 8):

Just as an alternative, if you know specifically what type of file it is...

```
sudo apt-get install foremost
```

Now open up `/etc/foremost.conf` and you will see a long list of commented out lines. If your file type exists, uncomment the line (you may also want to remove the irrelevant lines).

If your file type does not exist, add your own line. Say I want to recover a .css file and I know its around 40K. I could do add this:

```
css     n       40000   Theme\sName:     Plugin\sFixes
```

The 2nd column refers to case-sensitivity, the third column refers to the upper limit for size, the 4th column is how the file starts (remember to use escaped characters) and the last column is how the file usually ends.

Use the following command (edit the disk accordingly. could check with `df` command)

```
foremost -v -T -c /etc/foremost.conf -i /dev/sda -o output
```

What will happen next is that foremost will create a folder called output and dump all the recovered data (in this case) into the folder. From there you could use `diff` or `meld` to compare the recovered 'files' and see which is the most up to date.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. I accidentally removed my `php` source file using `rm -fr php/` with 2 `php` files. Less than 2 minutes they were recovered perfectly. In the `.conf` file I added: `php     n       40000   <?php   ?>    ASCII`

Answer (score 5):

Speaking in the most abstract terms, whenever you delete a file on the graphical interface, the file is "moved" to a special "buffer", a directory called `trash`. You can locate it in your `home` directory, `~/.local/share/Trash/`. Files "deleted" from this directory, will be really deleted. This real deletion is what happens when you use `rm` on a file.

It's extremely hard to recover deleted files. Files in the file system are represented as nodes on a B-tree or the like. When a file is deleted using `rm`, the tree is updated, number of hardlinks are reduced, the corresponding entry in the directory listing is removed. If at all, your file had a hard link, your file is absolutely safe. You can do a `file / -samefile filename`. You can search the file if you remember its inode number too (this is hardly the case).

Another case is when none of the above possibilities is true. Whenever you `rm` a file, the file entry on the directory is removed, reducing the number of hardlinks by one. And if the number of hard links drops to zero, then the pointer to the file on the inode is dropped, or is marked to be deleted. Either way, your file "still" resides on the hard disk. The file is actually erased from hard disk only on subsequent remount. File recovery at such a time is extremely hard, involves going through the file system tree and the inodes representing actual disk block locations. There's a popular tool I've heard of, but never used it, called `extundelete`. Although there's no guarantee, its  worth giving a try.

Once you recover your files successfully or not, make haste to do regular backups. It's extremely simple on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but files deleted from a command-line with the "rm" and "rm -f" bypass the "Trashcan" you have on the Gnome desktop.

You may also want to ask if there are any extfs "undelete" tools like there are for FAT and NTFS.  (I don't know of any, but I'd be surprised if there were none.)

Comment: Oh... it's ok!. I thought it could be recovered from some location.

Answer (score 1):

> use "**rm-trash**" utility which handles puts them to trash for later retrieval and supports all options of "rm" command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nateshmbhat/rm-trash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rm-trash
```

"rm-trash" is

- meant to be used in place of rm
- handles all options that rm can take
- handles the file name collisions with the files already in trash
- handles some permission issues automatically
- if rm is called from any other script or indirectly then the system 'rm' command is used automatically
- shows the appropriate error messages like those which arise in `rm`

Answer (score 1):

just add an alias in your file in home folde `.bash_alias` or `.bash_profile`

```
alias rm='gio trash'
```