# How can I trash a file from the command line?

Tags: 10.10, command-line, delete

Can I make a shell script trash files instead of delete them?

In the past I used `gvfs-trash` but this doesn't appear to exist in Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: "This question has been asked *before*..." Hmm, that could use some rewording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-from-terminal-be-restored/6703#6703). It outlines the way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the `gvfs-bin` package installed. `gvfs-trash` is part of it.