# Recover deleted data with rm -rf on Wubi?

Tags: wubi, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted `/home` with `sudo rm -rf`.

I tried to restore it with testdisk, but because Ubuntu is from Wubi, it cannot list the filesystem and I don't know another way to do this.

How could I restore my data? It's important.

I'm using 10.10 on Wubi

Comment: Related, but not quite a dupe: [Can files/directories deleted from terminal be restored?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-from-terminal-be-restored)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be possible using photorec...
e.g. on my wubi install I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
sudo photorec /dev/loop0
[proceed]
[none] (partition type table)
P ext4 [search]
[ext2/ext3]
[free] (or I guess you could use [whole])
```

Then select some place to recover other than the wubi install (I assume you'd run this from a live CD, so select the local hard drive... I used /host/ubuntu )

Then hit Y to select and it runs.

Then check results. Here's some terminal output

```
bcbc@ubuntu:~$ sudo photorec /dev/loop0
PhotoRec 6.11, Data Recovery Utility, April 2009
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
PhotoRec exited normally.
bcbc@ubuntu:~$ ls /host/ubuntu
disks    recup_dir.1  recup_dir.3  recup_dir.5      Ubuntu.ico          winboot
install  recup_dir.2  recup_dir.4  tedwireless.txt  uninstall-wubi.exe
bcbc@ubuntu:~$ cd /host/ubuntu/recup_dir.1/
bcbc@ubuntu:/host/ubuntu/recup_dir.1$ ls
f0270448.txt  f1666616.txt  f1668496.txt  f1791600.txt  f2403160.txt
f0270472.txt  f1666624.txt  f1668528.txt  f1791608.txt  f2403176.txt
f0270488.txt  f1666632.txt  f1668560.txt  f1791616.txt  f2403208.txt
...
```

If you're running from a live cd, first mount your windows host and then the root.disk:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/win
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win #change /dev/sda1 for your own partition
sudo mount -o loop /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /mnt
```

Then you can proceed selecting the appropriate loop device.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for this, I will try. What about files recovered by photorec, when i tried first time i received a few image files and a lot of .txt, but what about .php or .css or .html? Does the photorec recover them?

Comment: According to http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec it recovers .php and .html, but .css is  not listed. You should be able to target specific types... see http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step#Selection_of_files_to_recover if you want to narrow down the results.

Comment: bcbc - thanks, this is right way to go, it recovered a lot of files, going to check them all )) this is better than nothing. I checked your answer as solution ;)

Comment: Good luck. Let us know how it goes

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, whether in wubi or standard ubuntu, when you remove things with `rm -rf`, its nigh impossible to recover.  There are tools out there, but their effectiveness is relatively low when you've used `rm -rf`

***EDIT***
One of the tools explained in a comment to this was `photorec`.  It may help to recover data, but it won't restore filenames or paths, so you'll have to figure out what is what on your own.  Also, it may not work because you're using Wubi and not a direct-to-drive installation.

Comment: Photorec was able to recover more than 75% of the data for me (after `rm -rf`). It's not suitable for recovering a whole partition, but if you want to save a few very important files, this is the way to go (it doesn't recover the filenames, so it takes a while to find the right file).

Comment: @arrange put an emphasis on "few". They deleted the entire `/home/` dir structure, according to their message. It's quite possible, then, that the section the `/home/` area was on is in fact screwed up beyond repair or recovery.  Also note this is `wubi` so not everything works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches to recovering data. The first is file carving which attempts to identify the start and end of files and extract them.
This is very good for certain types of files, but you lose the file names and file times. It is particularly good for jpeg images.

The second approach depends very much on the file system. You are probably using ext3 or ext4.
If you are using ext3, then sleuthkit should work. However, I believe that sleuthkit doesn't yet handle ext4.
If your file system is ext3, try:

```
sudo apt-get install sleuthkit
```

and run

```
fls -r <device name of your home directory>
```

e.g.

```
fls -r /dev/sda1
```

(I haven't used WUBI so I don't know where your home partition might be.)

This will show you the file names which may be recoverable. If they are recoverable, then icat can be used to recover them.

Comment: Wubi doesnt use a partition. Wubi is installed inside of Windows, and runs off of a virtual image file which acts like the hard drive containing all the data. It does not actually sit on the drive as its own partition. Subsequently, as the partition does not exist for the Linux OS, your above-stated method probably will not work

Comment: Yep, i tried this method, also with testdisk and photorec but nothing of this worked...

My mind goes crazy now. :(

Comment: @Shogun there's really no other methods left for you to try, then. Because 99.99% of the time removing anything via terminal even with just `rm` is irrecoverable. Unfortunately, there's no solution to your issue, since neither worked (by the way I DID mention recovery would be almost impossible in my answer).

Comment: OK. Thanks All for answers, Going to buy soap and a rope... =))

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try my tool - http://freshmeat.net/projects/extcarve
"extcarve is a ext2/ext3/ext4 file recovery and semantic file carving tool. It can recover a range of file formats, including PNG, JPG, GIF, PDF, C/C++ programs, PHP, and HTML"

Comment: Thanks, but I already done with this using photorec.