# After re-installing wubi/ubuntu and use old root.disk , I get thrown to Grub shell

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, wubi

My wubi files were corrupted and i had to re-install ubuntu (through wubi) again. Before i un-installed the old ubuntu i saved the old root.disk in external drive.After i installed i tried to boot ubuntu (12.04 LTS), to make sure it works.Everything works fine. But when i copy the old root.disk in ubuntu/disks folder and boot to ubuntu it takes me to Grub shell/command line.After browsing online i came across [this soulution](http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=10036.15)

```
  set root=(hd0,1)
  loopback (loop0) /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
  set root=(loop0)
  linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro
  initrd /initrd.img
  boot
```

Line number 4 doesn't work, doesnt seem like there is file `vmlinuz-...`
Can somebody please give me step by step commands to boot into ubuntu.
My machine is window 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `root.disk` you copied wasn't corrupted... you can boot it as follows:

```
search -s -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $root
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

After booting, make sure you run `sudo update-grub`

Wubi corruption is most common on the `NTFS` file system (requires running `chkdsk /f` from Windows), followed by corruption of the internal `ext3/4` filesystem. Since you managed to copy your `root.disk` you may have internal corruption, in which case running `fsck root.disk` might fix it. But this depends on when you made your backup (i.e. before or after you encountered the problem).

To `fsck` the `root.disk` you can boot an Ubuntu DVD/USB, Select *Try Ubuntu*, then mount the partition that contains the `root.disk` and then `fsck` it as follows (this example assumes the `root.disk` is on `/dev/sda1`):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo fsck -fyv /mnt/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
```

(flags are `f`orce, `y`es to fix automatically, `v`erbose)

**Note**: `fsck` used in this way does make changes and there's no guarantee it will fix everything without data loss. If recovery is critical it's possible to use `photorec` (which comes bundled when you install `testdisk` i.e. `sudo apt-get install testdisk`). Photorec is read-only (non-destructive) and can recover raw files. The downside is that the recovered files are not named, and it recovers everything e.g. deleted files as well - so there is some manual effort to find the ones you are after. It does provide the ability to target specific file types though. See here for more info: [Recover deleted data with rm -rf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52693/recover-deleted-data-with-rm-rf)

Comment: Ok I am going to try it today. Please bare with me i had other issues on windows side.What is the line probe --set=diskuuid .... for?

Comment: @sparks `probe --set=diskuuid` gets the UUID of the partition that the `root.disk` resides on. Previously you'd have needed either the UUID of the partition number (`/dev/sdXY`) to boot and this isn't always obvious.

Comment: When I do linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid .... I get error file not found

Comment: @sparks I'd try mounting the `root.disk` from a liveCD to attempt data recovery and then `fsck`ing it. It seems likely that it's corrupted.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, but I don't have a live cd though.

Comment: @sparks you could create one, or if you do a fresh Wubi install, you could use that to `fsck` the `root.disk` of the old one. If you create one you could also do a normal dual boot which is more reliable than Wubi which is designed more to try out Ubuntu.

Comment: I wanted to copy my files from the old root.disk with ext2read first, but the home folder is not browsable and it is 0 bytes. The root.disk itself is 17 gb tthough. Any ideas what is going on?I have tried running chkdsk in C:\ several times. In that case  booting with CD/usb will make a difference? T

Comment: @sparks this is likely `ext3/4` filesystem corruption. The only way to fix that is `fsck` (`e2fsck`). There is no guarantee it will, but without it, you have 0 bytes in `/home` so... that appears to be your only option. For a pure data recovery there is one other alternative (I'll add to answer).