# Command to move a file to Trash via Terminal

Tags: command-line, files, trash

I would like to know if there is a command I can issue in a terminal so I do not classically remove (`rm`) the file, but instead move it to trash (i.e. Nautilus Move to Trash behavior).

In case there is such a command, I would also be interested in knowing what it is.

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/6703/74307).

Comment: Also a good resource here: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/make-rm-move-files-to-trash-instead-of.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As of 2017, `gvfs-trash` seems to be [deprecated](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gvfs-trash.1.html#description).

```
$ touch test
$ gvfs-trash test
This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio trash' instead.
See 'gio help trash' for more info.
```

You should use `gio`, specifically

```
gio trash
```

is the recommended way.

Comment: Could you link a source for `gvfs-trash` being deprecated and what `gio` is?

Comment: I can't provide a link unfortunately, but this is what I get trying to use gvfs-trash on Kubuntu 17.10: https://pastebin.com/HA4a1pbs

Comment: You could paste the example here in your answer, it would be sufficient for me together with system version number. I am using 16.04 LTS and `gvfs-trash` is the only option here.

Comment: This tool has a bunch of other nice features. I like the `info` command; it seems useful.

Comment: @Melebius On Bionic Beaver (18.04), [`gvfs-trash(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gvfs-trash.1.html) says that it has been deprecated. On Focal Fossa (20.04) even the [package description](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gvfs-bin) says that it's deprecated.

Answer (score 143):

As of 2017, you can use `gio`, which supports several operations, including trashing files.

```
gio trash filename
gio trash *.ext
gio trash filename1 filename2
```

From the manual:

```
Usage:
  gio trash [OPTION…] [LOCATION…]

Move/Restore files or directories to the trash.

Options:
  -f, --force     Ignore nonexistent files, never prompt
  --empty         Empty the trash
  --list          List files in the trash with their original locations
  --restore       Restore a file from trash to its original location (possibly recreating the directory)

Note: for --restore switch, if the original location of the trashed file
already exists, it will not be overwritten unless --force is set.
```

You used to be able to use `gvfs-trash` command from the package `gvfs-bin`. This is still installed by default in Ubuntu, but has been deprecated.

Comment: Also visit my [gvfs-question](http://askubuntu.com/q/499523/256099).

Comment: This is the simplest answer for me that works. Thank you.

Comment: According to `man gvfs-trash` it is deprecated in favour of `gio trash`, see `man gio`.

Comment: @pbhj 
ever this one appears to be having a problem handling pathname autocompletion when it entails spaces

Answer (score 84):

Install [trash-cli [image: Install trash-cli]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/trash-cli) – `sudo apt-get install trash-cli`

Put files in the trash with: `trash file1 file2`

List files in trash: [`trash-list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/trash-list.1.html)

Empty trash with: [`trash-empty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/trash-empty.1.html)

Comment: That (Ubuntu-related) tool points forward to a [trash spec](https://standards.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html). Pretty interesting, not sure how widely adopted, though...

Comment: After installation, I run the command and get the error:   `File "/usr/bin/trash-list", line 4, in <module> ImportError: No module named 'trashcli'`

Answer (score 18):

Updating `@Radu Rădeanu` answer. Since Ubuntu is telling me to use `gio` instead...

So, to trash `some_file` (or folder) use

```
gio trash some_file
```

To go dumpster diving use

```
gio list trash://
```

To empty trash

```
gio trash --empty
```

Comment: `gio list trash://`
`gio: trash://: Operation not supported`

Comment: It's missing one slash, it should be `gio list trash:///`. I tried to edit the answer but it doesn't allow me to make an edit of only one character.

Comment: either double or triple slash works for me on 18.04, tip, you can always add ```bash or other formatting rules if you only want to make minor character edits

Answer (score 5):

I like the simpler ways better.  I made a folder `.Tr` in my home directory by typing:

```
mkdir ~/.Tr
```

and instead of using `rm` to delete files, I move those files to the `~/.Tr` directory by typing:

```
mv fileName ~/.Tr
```

This is an effective and simple way of keeping access to files you think you don't want. This has the added benefit (in my case) of not messing with the system's folders, as my Ubuntu knowledge levels are fairly low and I worry about what I might be screwing up when I mess with system stuff.  If you are also low level please note that the "." in the directory name makes it a hidden directory.

Comment: The downside of using this approach is that moving files with the same name will overwrite them. When you use the gnome's trash that doesn't happen, it keeps all of them

Answer (score 3):

A previous answer mentions the command gio trash, which is fine as far as it goes. However, on server machines, there is no equivalent of a trash directory. I've written a Bash script that does the job; on (Ubuntu) desktop machines, it uses gio trash. (I've added `alias tt='move-to-trash'` to my alias definitions file; `tt` is a mnemonic for "to trash".) The script is tested to work; I use it all the time myself. **Script updated on 2020-08-10.**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# move-to-trash
#
# Teemu Leisti 2020-08-10
#
# This script moves the files given as arguments to the trash directory, if they
# are not already there. It works both on (Gnome) desktop and server hosts. (The
# gio command only exists for Gnome.)
#
# The script is intended as a command-line equivalent of deleting a file from a
# graphical file manager, which, in the usual case, moves the deleted file(s) to
# a built-in trash directory. On server hosts, the analogy is not perfect, as
# the script does not offer the functionality of restoring a trashed file to its
# original location, nor that of emptying the trash directory; rather, it offers
# an alternative to the 'rm' command, giving the user the peace of mind that
# they can still undo an unintended deletion before emptying the trash
# directory.
#
# To determine whether it's running on a desktop host, the script tests for the
# existence of the gio command and of directory ~/.local/share/Trash. In case
# both exist, the script relies on the 'gio trash' command. Otherwise, it treats
# the host as a server.
#
# There is no built-in trash directory on server hosts, so the script creates
# directory ~/.Trash/, unless it already exists.
#
# The script appends a millisecond-resolution time stamp to all the files it
# moves to the trash directory, both to inform the user of the time of the
# deletion, and to avoid overwrites when moving a file to trash.
#
# The script will not choke on a nonexistent file. It outputs the final
# disposition of each argument: does not exist, was already in trash, or was
# moved to trash.


gio_command_exists=0
command -v gio > /dev/null 2>&1
if (( $? == 0 )) ; then
    gio_command_exists=1
fi

# Exit on using an uninitialized variable, and on a command returning an error.
# (The latter setting necessitates appending " || true" to those arithmetic
# calculations and other commands that can return 0, lest the shell interpret
# the result as signalling an error.)
set -eu

is_desktop=0

if [[ -d ~/.local/share/Trash ]] && (( gio_command_exists == 1 )) ; then
    is_desktop=1
    trash_dir_abspath=$(realpath ~/.local/share/Trash)
else
    trash_dir_abspath=$(realpath ~/.Trash)
    if [[ -e $trash_dir_abspath ]] ; then
        if [[ ! -d $trash_dir_abspath ]] ; then
            echo "The file $trash_dir_abspath exists, but is not a directory. Exiting."
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        mkdir $trash_dir_abspath
        echo "Created directory $trash_dir_abspath"
    fi
fi

for file in "$@" ; do
    file_abspath=$(realpath -- "$file")
    file_basename=$(basename -- "$file_abspath")
    if [[ ! -e $file_abspath ]] ; then
        echo "does not exist:   $file_abspath"
    elif [[ "$file_abspath" == "$trash_dir_abspath"* ]] ; then
        echo "already in trash: $file_abspath"
    else
        if (( is_desktop == 1 )) ; then
            gio trash "$file_abspath" || true
        else
            # The name of the moved file shall be the original name plus a
            # millisecond-resolution timestamp.
            beginning="$trash_dir_abspath/$file_basename"_DELETED_ON_
            move_to_abspath="$beginning$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_AT_%H-%M-%S.%3N')"
            while [[ -e "$move_to_abspath" ]] ; do
                # Generate a new name with a new timestamp, as the previously
                # generated one denoted an existing file.
                move_to_abspath="$beginning$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_AT_%H-%M-%S.%3N')"
            done
            # We're now almost certain that the file denoted by name
            # $move_to_abspath does not exist. For that to be the case, an
            # extremely unlikely race condition would have had to take place:
            # some other process would have had to create a file with the name
            # $move_to_abspath after the execution of the existence test above.
            # However, to make absolute sure that moving the file to the trash
            # directory will always be successful, we shall give the '-f'
            # (force) flag to the 'mv' command.
            /bin/mv -f "$file_abspath" "$move_to_abspath"
        fi
        echo "moved to trash:   $file_abspath"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In KDE 4.14.8 I used the following command to move files to trash (as if it were removed in Dolphin):

```
kioclient move path_to_file_or_directory_to_be_removed trash:/
```

Appendix: I found about the command with

```
    ktrash --help
...
    Note: to move files to the trash, do not use ktrash, but "kioclient move 'url' trash:/"
```

EDIT : For KDE 5.18.5, the command is `kioclient5`, the syntax is identical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open-source [nodejs-based version](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash) (if you want to know what happens under the hood, or need this in a project) that also has [command line support](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash#cli) (if you are happy if it just works).

```
> trash pictures/beach.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `gio trash` as `gvfs-trash` is deprecated.

1. Open the terminal and type the below command:

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. This command will open your `.bashrc` file, which is the configuration file for your terminal. If you are using any other terminal open their `rc` file (e.g. `zsh` terminal will be like `.zshrc`).
3. Paste the below command at the end of your opened file:

   ```
   alias rm='gio trash'
   ```
4. Now just save and exit the file.
5. Restart your terminal and Boom, you have successfully changed `rm` from permanently deleting a file to deleting the file to trash!!

Comment: Does `gio trash` take all of the command line arguments of `rm`?