# What is the difference between gvfs commands and common commands like cat, ls, cp?

Tags: command-line, gvfs

I recently found the following **gvfs commands** :

```
gvfs-cat (1)         - Concatenate files
gvfs-copy (1)        - Copy files
gvfs-info (1)        - Show information about files
gvfs-ls (1)          - List files
gvfs-mime (1)        - Get or set mime handlers
gvfs-mkdir (1)       - Create directories
gvfs-monitor-dir (1) - Monitor directories for changes              
gvfs-monitor-file (1) - Monitor files for changes
gvfs-mount (1)       - Mounts the locations
gvfs-move (1)        - Copy files
gvfs-open (1)        - Open files with the default handler
gvfs-rename (1)      - Rename a file
gvfs-rm (1)          - Delete files
gvfs-save (1)        - Save standard input
gvfs-set-attribute (1) - Set file attributes
gvfs-trash (1)       - Move files or directories to the trash
gvfs-tree (1)        - List contents of directories in a tree-like format
```

Now, **how do these differ by the common commands** like `cat`, `cp`, `mkdir`, etc.

In other words what is the difference between the following commands respectively:

- `cat` and `gvfs-cat`
- `cp` and `gvfs-copy`
- `mkdir` and `gvfs-mkdir` etc. and so on.

or **what for `gvfs-*` commands stands for**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`gvfs-...` type commands can process remote locations based on a url.

From `man gvfs-cat`:

> gvfs-cat works just like the traditional cat utility,
>     but using gvfs locations instead of local files:
>     for example you can use something like smb://server/resource/file.txt as location.

---

For instance

You can use `gvfs-cat` to do the following:

```
gvfs-cat smb://server/resource/file.txt
```

But `cat` can only be used to do this:

```
$ cat /path/to/some/file.txt
```

`cat` can only access local files, making it useful for local drive lookups. `gvfs-cat` is used for remote lookups with a valid GVFS url.