# Google Drive Repository from the terminal

Tags: 20.04, google-drive

How can I access this repository from terminal? It is the access to my google drive account from the desktop. Is there a way to make it accessible from `\home`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Nautilus so slow in copying files to Google Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254449/why-is-nautilus-so-slow-in-copying-files-to-google-drive)

Comment: I don't remember how I got it to work, but check out https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse .

Answer (score 10):

You should use `rclone` (use `apt install rclone` to install it) and configure it for "Google Drive". Detailed information on how to configure `rclone` for "Google Drive" is given at https://rclone.org/drive/.

<sub>You can follow the recommendation at the step **Google Application Client Id**. Check out [Making your own client_id](https://rclone.org/drive/#making-your-own-client-id), it provides a great guide for setting up `client_id` (as of June 2023).</sub>

Once you've completed the configuration, *mount* your "Google Drive" with the following command:

```
rclone -v --vfs-cache-mode writes mount "$rdrive": "$ldrive"
```

Here `$rdrive` is the `remote:` string configured in the reference given above; `$ldrive` is a local empty directory (like `~/MyGoogleDrive`). You should, `mkdir "$ldrive"` first as `rclone` won't do that itself. Once executed, the *mount* command will *not* return, which means it is working correctly. The specified `remote:` will be *mounted* until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

---

Similarly you can configure and use "Microsoft One Drive" and many other cloud providers. A complete list of the cloud providers supported by `rclone` can be found at https://rclone.org/.

Comment: It says `Error: unknown flag: --vfs-cache-mode`

Comment: What is your version of rclone? See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/rclone.1.html

Comment: @FedKad it seems that you have typo in rclone command, it should be `rclone mount --daemon --vfs-cache-mode writes my_rclone_gdrive: /home/user/my_fs_dir_for_gdrive
`

Comment: @Divelix If you are talking about the `--daemon` option, I deliberately used the "foreground mode" of `rclone`, so that it will be terminated via Ctrl+C.

Comment: @FedKad, sorry, I meant that when I used flags (`-v --vfs-cache-mode writes`) before `mount`, it didn't work for me. There's nothing about `--daemon`, I just added it by mistake.

Comment: @FedKad, I just tried again and it works fine as you wrote it too. Probably my problem was in something else at first try.

Comment: that seems to be the way out, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Such Google Drive location is placed in directory like

```
/run/user/$UID/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=username/
```

But it is useless because of crypted file names like `1N-QaxXtI-N3PimnrqloO3uNl7Thq3PUB`.

Comment: Is there a way to have an alias in `/home` It is not that usefull to access `run/user/$UID/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=username/`

Comment: You can mount this folder manually and then create symlink for it. Or use rclone as stated in other answer. But my recommendation is to use DropBox with its great integration to file-managers. Google does not release official normal Drive client for linux.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the synchronism by GNOME is done via [`gio`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software)), which has the path `google-drive://username@gmail.com/` on a GUI file manager, but it is actually stored at `/run/user/...` on your GNU/Linux filesystem.

GIO (Gnome Input/Output) seems to not be optimized to work on terminal. You can even `ls` through your directories by using `gio list -d google-drive://username@gmail.com/path/to/directory`, but it does not seem possible to make more sophisticated stuffs, such as symlink...

In nutshell, if you are like me and have a full-based terminal workflow, then maybe I had better to use [`rclone`](https://github.com/rclone/rclone), which is a terminal program that allows you to get a full control of your files from terminal. It is a little bit trickier to set this up, but it is much more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @FedKad solution above. Posting a new answer because I exceeded the limit for a comment.

Steps:

1. I installed rclone in Ubuntu (`sudo apt install rclone`)
2. Followed the instructions at https://rclone.org/drive/ (choosing Google Drive, option 13, and the rest mostly defaults),
3. Got redirected to my Google account, signed in and got authenticated, and finished the rest of the setup.

To mount was a bit more trickier but after seeing this issue https://forum.rclone.org/t/what-does-poll-interval-is-not-supported-by-this-remote-mean/4771 I opted to dump all the other flags and just did

```
rclone mount "GoogleDrive:" "NameOfMyDriveOnMyLocalMachine"
```

and it worked wonders.

I am now able to navigate via the Terminal with proper file and directory names.

Do note that you must first create "NameOfMyDriveOnMyLocalMachine" and that's where you'll find your drive files. Also note that the colon after your drive vendor name is necessary **inside the quotes**.

As stated above, leave the command above hanging, and work from another terminal in a tab or new application.

Hope that simplifies @FedKad's solution above.