# Editing files from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, editing

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

I've set up a Google Account under 'Online Accounts', and have given access to files, and the account is showing up as I expected in the File Manager.

I can open files simply by double clicking on them, but don't seem to be able to edit and save text files back to the same location using gVim.

The filename in the application header is a random link name from Google, so, performing a 'save' just creates a file with (part of) that name, and the ORIGINAL contents of the file (as well as showing error messages within gVim).

Is there a trick to editing files directly in the Drive location on Ubuntu? Or is this just not possible and the files have to be copied locally, edited, and then copied back?

Thanks

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1332053/66509 . This is a reason to use Dropbox as alternative. Or maybe MEGA.

Comment: Or mount the drive with rclone