# Random names instead of actual file & directory names when using Google Drive

Tags: mount, online-accounts, google-drive

I have mounted my Google Drive after logging in using Online Accounts from Settings. I am able to browse all my Drive folders and files through Nautilus after mounting.

But when I open a file - like in a text editor - I see a long random string instead of the file name. This also happens with directory names. Is there a way to see the actual file & directory names while in use?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1332056/855322

Comment: @FedKad I ended up using rclone. Thanks.