# Can I add a cloud service to Ubuntu Online Accounts?

Tags: .desktop, sync, online-accounts

Ubuntu offers connection and synchronisation to a very limited set of online cloud services, such as Google, Next cloud and a few others. My question is, can a new service be added to this predefined list? If yes, how?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1332056/855322

Comment: @FedKad thanks! Partially Rclone helps, but not fully. Rclone will sync my files, but Ubuntu online accounts also synchronise mail, calendar, contacts and a couple other things unimportant to me.