# Google Drive Nautilus Mount Point

Tags: mount, mountpoint, google-drive

As per this [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mount-google-drive-ubuntu/), I am able to get nautilus integration with google drive and can manually copy files into google drive via the GUI, however I would like to be able to write a small shell script to do backups periodically via `cron`. I cannot seem to find where this is actually mounted?

Via nautilus I see it at `google-drive://my.email@gmail.com/` however am a bit confused how this is actually connected/mounted so nautilus can see it and where I can `cp` files to?

Comment: Maybe Use ocamlfuse, and create a Local Folder to use....https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse. The startup is not exactly right...Here's mine....`@reboot sleep 30 && google-drive-ocamlfuse -o allow_other ~/google/`

Comment: By Default, ocamlfuse is only available to root, so that is why `-o allow_other` is necessary. Authorization Step is Here...https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Authorization

Comment: Given that I can drag and drop files for syncing with `nautilus`, is there not a way to do this without using a third party application? Given that I am using `Ubuntu 18.04` which has built in support via `Setting -> Online Accounts -> Google`

Comment: If it were a mounted filesystem, then you'd be able to see it. There is no mounted filesystem. That files app.... it just uses api calls to get a file listing, and show you some files in a window, then when you click on them or drag them etc, it copies that one file to wherever... Just like using the google drive web interface.

Comment: Ahhh, okay thanks for clearing up the confusion @EODCraftStaff

Answer (score 5):

Nautilus integration with google drive uses GVfs (abbreviation for GNOME Virtual file system). You can find GVfs mountpoints in:

```
/run/user/XXXX/gvfs
```

where XXXX is the UID of your user.

In my computer, google drive mountpoint is on `/run/user/1000/gvfs/...`.

You can find the list of GVfs mounted filesystems running the following command:

```
gvfs-mount --list -i
```

If you want copy Google Drive files using terminal, you must use the `gvfs-copy` command instead `cp`.

As despicted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499523/what-is-the-difference-between-gvfs-commands-and-common-commands-like-cat-ls-c), there are specific `gvfs-...` type commands to process files in remote locations.