# How to delete to trash via terminal (with mv command)?

Tags: command-line, trash, mv

I would like to know how can I delete a file and/or move it to trash with `mv` command?

I know where the trash located is, then I tried with this commands to move it to trash:

```
mv somefile /home/username/.local/share/Trash
```

this command work fine, but when I open trash in launcher it's still show empty. I can undo this deleted file in original location with:

```
mv /home/username/.local/share/Trash/somefile ~/
```

but if this location `/home/username/.local/share/Trash` isn't for Trash then where is moved my file?

I know `rm` will permanently delete file and not send it to a trash folder and there is no flag in `man rm` to delete file to trash.

Comment: Also see this recent question+answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213533/command-to-move-a-file-to-trash-via-terminal

Comment: I missed out on that one! Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: If you will use `mv` to move a file to trash, you will never enjoy the option to restore that file from the trash! From here my downvote (sorry).

Comment: Ok, then what is your reason to put things in the trash? Just to have things there? Perhaps you do not understand the point of the trash. A novice user can take your idea as a good advice and this is not desirable.

Comment: @KasiyA It's still not right. How you will reverse after you used `mv` command twice for two different files from different directories, but with the same name? Not to say that you have to remember all the time which was the previous file location.

Comment: @KasiyA You have [steeldriver's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/523907/147044). See `man gvfs-trash` for more info.

Comment: @KasiyA Another reason for downvote: your terminology is not correct: You can *delete* something **from ...**, but not **to ...**. When you delete something from one location and then you see that thing at another location implies an action which is called *move* (not *delete*).

Comment: @KasiyA Looking for what?!?... You are looking in the wrong direction. I told you: the answer is [there](http://askubuntu.com/a/523907/147044) and has explained why `mv` is bad in this case.

Comment: @KasiyA The only reason: `mv` doesn't has this property: to remember from where a file was moved (only you or `history` can do this).

Comment: @KasiyA I revised/improved my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/523909/256099)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Information about Trash directory:

`~/.local/share/Trash` contains two directories named `info` and `files`.

- `~/.local/share/Trash/files` contains original files.
- `~/.local/share/Trash/info` contains  files (extension : `.trashinfo`)which have information about path and deletion date of files.

Therefore, if you want to use `mv` command then follow command:

```
mv somefile ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```

**But it is not recommended to use above method to move files to trash.**(as commented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523906/how-to-delete-to-trash-via-terminal-with-mv-command/523909#comment714919_523906))

---

You can install trash command line i.e. **`trash-cli`** by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

And here are available commands for trash:

```
$ apropos trash
gvfs-trash (1)       - Move files or directories to the trash
restore-trash (1)    - Restore for Command line trash utility.
trash (1)            - Command line trash utility.
trash-empty (1)      - Empty for Command line trash utility.
trash-list (1)       - List trashed files.
trash-put (1)        - Command line trash utility.
```

**You can move/put files to trash by following command:**

1. **`trash-put somefiles`**
2. or **`gvfs-trash somefiles`**

**List** trash by command: **`trash-list`**
**Restore** files by command: **`restore-trash`**
**Empty** trash by command: **`trash-empty`**

Also visit [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/a/213549/256099) Question.

Comment: Also visit : http://linuxg.net/linux-and-unix-trash-list-trashed-files-restore-trashed-files-empty-trash/

Comment: I will never advice someone to use `mv` command to move a file to trash. See [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/523906/how-to-delete-to-trash-via-terminal-with-mv-command/523909#comment714919_523906) to understand why.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Ok. I revisied my answer to including all.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `gvfs-trash` instead of `mv`

```
gvfs-trash somefile
```

---

The reason you were unable to see your file after moving it to ~/.local/share/Trash is that there is an additional directory structure below that i.e.

- `~/.local/share/Trash/files` to contain the actual trashed file; and
- `~/.local/share/Trash/info` containing metadata such as the original location

Although you could have used

```
mv somefile ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```

in which case `somefile` *would* be visible in the trash can, it would not be possible to use the nautilus/gvfs `Restore` function to undelete the file, due to the lack of `info` metadata - you would need to know and manually `mv` the file to its original location. In that sense, only `gvfs-trash` is the exact command-line equivalent to trashing a file via nautilus.

Comment: @KasiyA That shouldn't happen with `gvfs-trash` since it's part of GNOME (i.e. integrates with other GNOME components such as Nautilus)

Comment: Also note that `gvfs-trash` elegantly handles the case of sending to the trash two independent files with identical names, but using `mv` the first "trashed" such file would be irreversibly gone.

Comment: `gvfs-trash` has been deprecated in favour of `gio trash`.

Comment: You can use the command `gvfs-trash --empty` to empty the trash from Terminal.