# how can I make an alias that does not fully remove the file like rm

Tags: command-line, trash, alias

how can I move a file to trash using an alias?

Comment: This was explained here http://askubuntu.com/questions/213533/command-to-move-a-file-to-trash-via-terminal/213549#213549

Comment: You don't know [how to create a permanent alias](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias) or you don't know about [a command which moves files to trash](http://askubuntu.com/q/213533/147044)? In each case your question is a duplicate. I will choose to close your question for the second reason.