# Delete all files except files with the extension pdf in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a directory that contains the following:

```
x.pdf
y.zip
z.mp3
a.pdf
```

I want to delete all files apart from `x.pdf` and `a.pdf`. How do I do this from the terminal? There are no subdirectories so no need for any recursion.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
cd <the directory you want>
find . -type f ! -iname "*.pdf" -delete
```

- The first command will take you to the directory in which you want to delete your files
- The second command will delete all files except with those ending with `.pdf` in filename

---

For example, if there is a directory called `temp` in your home folder:

```
cd ~/temp
```

then delete files:

```
find . -type f ! -iname "*.pdf" -delete
```

This will delete all files except `xyz.pdf`.

You can combine these two commands to:

```
find ~/temp -type f ! -iname "*.pdf" -delete
```

---

`.` is the current directory. `!` means to take all files except the ones with `.pdf` at the end. `-type f` selects only files, not directories. `-delete` means to delete it.

#### NOTE: this command will delete all files (except pdf files but including hidden files) in current directory as well as in all sub-directories. `!` must come before `-name`. simply `-name` will include only `.pdf`, while `-iname` will include both `.pdf` and `.PDF`

To delete only in current directory and not in sub-directories add `-maxdepth 1`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -iname "*.pdf" -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you help me understand the syntax a little? `.` means "and"? `!` means "except" `-name` signifies that you want to exclude by a name parameter and then `-delete` is the action to take upon finding? So it looks for everything except "*.pdf" and deletes them? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: `.` means current directory. `!` means to take all files except the one with `.pdf` at the end. `-delete` means to delete it. am i clear now ?

Comment: @terdon Starkers said that there are no sub-directories.wait ill edit my answer to be more broad

Comment: +1 You should have included the `-maxdepth 1` parameter to begin with. Then suggest removing the parameter in case one wants to delete recursively.

Comment: @user1598390 the user who posted the question he said there are no sub-directory. and for other users ill recommend to read out full answer before using it :)

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/556211/158442) brought to my attention that we should be using `-iname` instead of `-name`, or files with `.PDF` as an extension will slip through.

Comment: `-iname` will match also `.Pdf`, `.pDf`, `.pdF`, `.PDf`, `.pDF`, `.PdF` and so on.

Answer (score 45):

With `bash`'s extended shell globbing, you could remove any files with extensions other than `.pdf` using

```
rm -- *.!(pdf)
```

As noted by @pts, the `--` characters indicate the end of any command options, make the command safe in the rare case of files whose names start with a `-` character.

If you want to delete files without any extension as well as those with extensions other than `.pdf`, then as pointed out by @DennisWilliamson you could use

```
rm -- !(*.pdf)
```

Extended globbing should be enabled by default, but if not you can do so using

```
shopt -s extglob
```

---

Especially if you intend to use this inside a script, it's important to note that if the expression doesn't match anything (i.e. if there are no non-pdf files in the directory), then by default the glob will be passed unexpanded to the `rm` command, resulting in an error like

```
rm: cannot remove `*.!(pdf)': No such file or directory
```

You can modify this default behaviour using the `nullglob` shell option, however that has its own issue. For a more thorough discussion see [NullGlob - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob)

Comment: Better approach IMO.

Comment: What about files without an extension? FWIW, in zsh it’s `rm *~*.pdf`

Comment: I would put the dot inside the parentheses.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek it ignores files without any extension - it only deletes those *with extensions other than .pdf*

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I don't think `*!(.pdf)` will work as the `*` will match anything

Comment: Ah, the asterisk should also go inside: `!(*.py)`. Also, presumably, if the OP wants only ".pdf" files remaining, then files without extensions should also be deleted and not ignored.

Comment: This approach is simpler and neater than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

[Delete to trash](https://askubuntu.com/q/213533/283843):

```
$ cd <the directory you want>
$ gvfs-trash !(*.pdf)
```

Or via `mv` command (but in this way you cannot restore it from Trash since it doesn't record .trashinfo information, so this means you moved your files to a *destination* where it is as following).

```
mv !(*.pdf) ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```

Comment: This approach is much safer than directly using `rm`.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest approach:  Create another directory somewhere (if you're only deleting in one directory, not recursively, it can even be a subdirectory); move all the .pdf's there; delete everything else; move the pdf's back; delete the intermediate directory.

Quick, easy, you can see exactly what you're doing.  Just make sure the intermediate directory is on the same device as the directory you're cleaning up so that moves are renames, not copies!

Comment: +1 Again for a comment that makes sense to the novice user, that will almost certainly not result in deleting files unintentionally.

Answer (score 4):

Use bash's GLOBIGNORE:

```
GLOBIGNORE=x.pdf:a.pdf
rm *
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

From bash's man page:

```
GLOBIGNORE:

            A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set
            of filenames to be ignored by pathname expansion.
```

---

A quick test:

```
mkdir /tmp/foooooo
cd /tmp/foooooo
touch x.pdf y.zip z.mp3 a.pdf
GLOBIGNORE=x.pdf:a.pdf
ls -1 *
```

Output:

```
y.zip
z.mp3
```

Answer (score 3):

## Be careful and compose: use xargs

Here's an approach I like, because it lets me be very careful: compose a way to show just the files I want to delete, then send them to `rm` using `xargs`. For example:

- `ls` shows me everything
- `ls | grep pdf` shows me the files I want to keep. Hmm.
- `ls | grep -v pdf` shows the opposite: all *except* what I want to keep. In other words, it shows the list of things I want to delete. *I can confirm this before doing anything dangerous.*
- `ls | grep -v pdf | xargs rm` sends exactly that list to `rm` for deletion

As I said, I mainly like this for the safety it provides: no accidental `rm *` for me. Two other advantages:

- It's composable; you can use `ls` or `find` to get the initial list, as you prefer. You can use anything else you like in the process of narrowing that list - another `grep`, some `awk`, or whatever. If you needed to delete only files whose names contain a color, you could build it up this same way.
- You can use each tool for its main purpose. I prefer to use `find` for finding and `rm` for removal, as opposed to having to remember that `find` accepts a `-delete` flag. And if you do this, again, you can compose alternate solutions; maybe instead of `rm`, you could create a `trash` command that moves the file to the trash (allowing "undeletion") and pipe to that instead of `rm`. You don't need to have `find` support that option, you just pipe to it.

### Update

See comments by @pabouk for how modify this to handle some edge cases, such as line breaks in file names, filenames like `my_pdfs.zip`, etc.

Comment: I noticed three problems here: **a)** It will exclude any file containing `pdf` anywhere in its name. --- **b)** It will delete PDF files if any of the letter in the suffix are upper case. --- **c)** It is not a good idea to use output of `ls`. It will not work with file names containing newlines. Some implementations of `ls` replace special characters e.g. tab by `?`. --- It is better to use: `find -maxdepth 1 -print0`. (not so short as `ls` :) ----- To resolve a) and b) use `grep -vi '\.pdf$'` --- complete (but GNU only) solution: `find -maxdepth 1 -print0 | grep -viz '\.pdf$' | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: I understand that you meant the solution as an "interactive" process with multiple manual iterations but the checks will be hardly usable for long lists of files and the problems mentioned above could bring easy to overlook mistakes.

Comment: @pabouk good points; the real world always complicates things, and your corrections are helpful. :) But I still think this overall approach is best. If there are too many files to visually confirm everything, you can `| head -20` to at least see if it looks roughly correct, whereas if you just `rm my_pattern`, you have no chance to spot a big mistake.

Comment: You can have find show you the files before you delete them too,  leave out the -delete and just use `find . -type f ! -name "*.pdf"` to print to console, or pipe to less or a file. [and then pipe to xargs to rm if desired like pabouk's comments (with the -print0| ... -0 for weird filenames)]

Answer (score 3):

I usually solve such problems from the interactive Python interpreter:

```
mic@mic ~ $ python
>>> import os
>>> for f in os.listdir('.'):
...   if not f.endswith('.pdf'):
...     os.remove(f)
```

It might be longer than a one-liner with `find` or `xargs`, but it's extremely resilient, and I know exactly what it does, without having to research it first.

Comment: For those who get increasingly nervous with every additional line, we *could* make it into one: `for item in [f for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.endswith('.pdf')]: os.remove(item)`

Comment: `python -c "import os; for f in os.listdir('.'): if not f.endswith('.pdf'): os.remove(f)"`

Comment: `[os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.endswith('.pdf')]`

Comment: nice! the second one gives me a syntax error, don't see why.

Comment: strange; it works with both python 3.4 and python 2.7 on my system.

Comment: @JacobVlijm because you probably used single quotes in  `python -c '...'` , use `python -c "..."` (double quotes).

Comment: Just because I can, here's another one: `python -c 'import os;map(lambda x: os.remove(x), filter(lambda x: not x.endswith(".pdf"),os.listdir(".")))' `

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Wow, this is an old one :). Need to look into it what it was about Haha.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yeah, it's an old one. Showed up on the front page, so had to look through the answer if there's anything I could add

Answer (score 2):

Better answer (compared to my previous answer) to this question would be by using the powerful `file` command.

```
$ file -i abc.pdf
abc: application/pdf; charset=binary
```

now your problem:

```sh
cd <the directory you want to search in>
for var in ./*
do
  if file -i "$var" | grep -q 'application/pdf\;'
    then
    echo "$var"
  fi
done
```

The job of `for` command is give the files in current directory in the form of variable `$var`. `if-then` command outputs the names of pdf files by taking the exit status of `0` from `file -i "$var" | grep -q 'application/pdf\;'` command, it will give exit status of `0` only if it finds pdf files.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm $(ls -lo|grep -v [Pp][Dd][Ff]$|awk '{print $7}')
```

Warning! Better try first

```
ls -l $(ls -lo|grep -v [Pp][Dd][Ff]$|awk '{print $7}')
```

Comment: Ugh, this is flawed in so many ways: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#ls, http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#grep, and it totally ignores file names with white space or special characters.

Comment: You should really use `-i` with `grep` for case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -i -- !(*@(a|x).pdf)
```

Read as, remove all files that are not `a.pdf` or `x.pdf`.

This works by making use of 2 extended globs, the outer `!()` to negate the contained glob which itself requires that the glob must match one or more of `a` or `x` patterns before the `.pdf` suffix. See [glob#extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob).

```
$ ls -a
.dotfile1 .dotfile2 a.pdf x.pdf y.zip z.mp3

$ echo -- !(a.pdf)
-- x.pdf y.zip z.mp3

$ echo -- !(x.pdf)
-- a.pdf y.zip z.mp3

$ echo -- !(a.pdf|x.pdf)
-- y.zip z.mp3

$ echo -- !(@(a|x).pdf)   # NOTE.that this matches the .dotfiles* as well
-- . .. .dotfile1 .dotfile2 y.zip z.mp3

$ echo -- !(*@(a|x).pdf)  # but this doesn't
-- y.zip z.mp3

$ echo rm -i -- !(*@(a|x).pdf)
rm -i -- y.zip z.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

#### portable shell way

```
$ ksh -c 'for i in ./*; do case $i in *.pdf)continue;; *)rm "$i";; esac;done'
```

Pretty much POSIX and compatible with any Bourne-style shell ( `ksh`, `bash`, `dash` ). Well suited for portable scripts and when you can't use `bash`'s extended shell globbing.

#### perl:

```
$ perl -le 'opendir(my $d,"."); foreach my $f (grep(-f && !/.pdf/ , readdir($d))){unlink $f};closedir $d'
```

Or slightly cleaner:

```
$ perl -le 'opendir(my $d,"."); map{ unlink $_ } grep(-f "./$_" && !/.pdf/ , readdir($d));closedir $d'
```

#### alternative python

```
python -c 'import os;map(lambda x: os.remove(x), filter(lambda x: not x.endswith(".pdf"),os.listdir(".")))'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Be Careful of what you're deleting!**

A safe way to test it before trying to delete is to test first with `ls`, as some uncaught behaviors could delete unwanted files. And you can do it directly outside of the directory. `ls` is similar to `rm`, so :

```
ls sub/path/to/files/!(*.pdf)
```

This will list

```
y.zip
z.mp3
```

And now you can see what you're deleting and can safely delete them :

```
rm sub/path/to/files/!(*.pdf)
```

And that's it. Yo can use wildcard `*` to be more selective like keeping only programming course documents :

```
rm sub/path/to/files/!(*programming*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution would work for most cases.

I got hundreds of directories but I have exception for some directories files.

1. Zip all files that is not for deletion to `my_files.zip`. If there are directories, you need to add the recursive command.

   ```
   zip -r my_files.zip a.php b.txt c.dll directory1 directory2
   ```
2. Delete all files recursively(thoroughly) except myfiles.zip

   ```sh
   #extended globbing allows for more advanced pattern matching.
   shopt -s extglob

   #delete all file
   rm -r -- !(my_files.zip)
   ```
3. Unzip my_files.zip

   ```
   unzip my_files.zip
   ```