# How to delete files with the same extension in one go using rm?

Tags: command-line

I had compiled many `C` programs together, and each of the file had a `.gch` created. Now I did not want the `.gch` files so I decided to delete them. But it would take lots of time using `rm` for deleting each file. So is there a way to remove files with the same extension in one go?

**NOTE:** I work in Ubuntu 14.04. I want the solution to be in `shell` or `terminal`. The question is not a duplicate as I want to use `rm` only.

Comment: Recursively or non-recursively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all files except files with the extension pdf in a directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/555318/delete-all-files-except-files-with-the-extension-pdf-in-a-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recursively delete all files of a specific extension in the current directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377438/how-can-i-recursively-delete-all-files-of-a-specific-extension-in-the-current-di)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easily use the expansion"*":

```
rm /path-to-directory/*.gch
```

This what is called filename expansion which use some special characters called wildcards.

suppose you have a directory containing the files (file, file0, file1, file01)

Some know wildcards:

**The question mark** (**?**) is a special character that causes the shell to generate filenames. It matches any single character in the name of an existing file.

example:

```
ls file?
```

The shell expands the "file?" argument and generates a list of files in the working directory that have names composed of "file" followed by any single character.

Then the output would be file0 and file1

**The asterisk (*)** performs a function similar to that of the question mark but matches any number of characters, including zero characters, in a filename.

now the output of the command:

```
ls file*
```

would be file, file0, file1 and also file01

**The [ ] Special Characters**  causes the shell to match filenames containing the individual characters within the brackets.

for example the output of the command:

```
ls file[01]*
```

would be:

file0 file1 file01

This is just a simple introduction for shell expansion, you can read more :

- http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php
- http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Comment: To be noted that `file[01]*` matches `file01` because the `*` matches anything after `file0` or `file1`, the square brackets in globbing patterns always match a single character in the class and this behavior can't be changed with `{}`, `*` or `+` like in regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

To remove files with the same extension in one-go, just use `find` command.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -iname '*.gch' -delete
```

- `-type` tells `find` if you are searching for `files` or `directories`, here:

  `f` = file

  `d` = directory
- `iname` tells `find` about the name of the file you are looking for.

  **Note**: `name` does the same thing but `iname` is recommended because it ignores cases whereas `name` doesn't.
- `-delete` deletes those files

Answer (score 1):

Simply type the following command in terminal (shell)

```
rm -rf  /path/to/files/*.<extension>
```

Be careful with the -f parameter. It will not warn before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C and Makefiles, you can also make a .PHONY recipe target and rm by default and add the byproduct "cruft" files that one deletes from a clean source directory. You still use the wildcard * token.

```
make clean
```

for example

```
   .PHONY clean


    clean:  
         rm -f *.gch  *.o *.temp *.log
```

then you have multiplied your productivity in cruft elimination.