# How to remove all files except .jpeg?

Tags: bash, delete, find

I have a folder that consists of other folders (whose names are unknown), `.tar` archives and JPEG images. How can I remove everything except `.jpeg` files?

Comment: Essentially the same as [Delete all files except files with the extension pdf in a directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/555318/delete-all-files-except-files-with-the-extension-pdf-in-a-directory)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use below command :

`ls -1 | grep -v "jpeg" | xargs -I {} rm -rf {}`.

`ls -1` show all content of your directory `-1` will show each file in one line .

`grep -v "jpeg"` work in reverse mode means just only those file that's not end with "jpeg" .

and last command `xargs` accept each file name from previous command and pass it to `rm` command to delete those file.