# How to make my script executeable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm new to Linux and I've written a script to move files to a specified folder (fake delete).
However it will only `mv` the file in the same folder as my script. Is there a way I can make this executable to delete any file no matter the location?

I.e.:

> DELETE test ..(test is in ~/my-documents folder) (delete script in ~/my-applications/bin folder)

The script is below.

```
echo do you want to delete this? (yes/no) \n
read ans \n
case "$ans" in
  Y¦y¦yes ) echo "$readlink -f "$1")" >>"$HOME/DustbinLog" && mv "$1" "$HOME/my-applications/bin/dustbin";; 
  N¦n¦no echo "File not moved!";;     
esac
```

Comment: The shell can't guess where the file is, specially because there might be files with the same name in different folders. You have to specify the path to the file you want to delete. If it is in ~/my-documents run `DELETE ~/my-documents/test`.

Comment: Also, I think it might have been a mistake while writing the question (since you apparently tested the script and it worked on your current folder), but there are some mistakes in the code there. The newline characters, the `or` operator (should be `|`, not `¦`), the second option from the `case` is missing a `)`. I also would use a default case in the "no" answer (`*)`). That way, if the user types anything but Y/y/yes the file won't be moved and the message will be prompted.

Comment: This might also interest you: http://askubuntu.com/q/213533/457562

Comment: many thanks. yes your are right I miss typed my code on here. and thank you for the suggestion on the asterix ..

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to be in the pwd for the DELETE command to work or put the exact path name.. thanks..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)