# Restoring files from trash in Space File Manager

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, trash

I'm using Space File Manager in my Ubuntu 18.04 as a substitute for Nautilus File Manager. But SpaceFM doesn't have an option to move deleted files to trash. Instead it deletes them permanently. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087139/775359) to add a new command that moves selected files to trash when pressing `delete`.

However, if I want to restore after deleting, neither `ctrl+Z` works nor going to trash and right click and select restore (no restore option). How can I get this functionality in Space FM? i.e. to restore files when pressing `ctrl+Z` and right click within trash and select restore.