# when deleting multiple files or folders what do you recommend to be safe?

Tags: command-line, bash, delete, rm

When it comes to removing files. Instead of

```
rm some_file.txt
```

or

```
rm -rf some_folder
```

we do

```
del some_file.txt
```

or

```
del some_folder
```

where you can define your bash alias for `del` in ~/.custom_aliases as

```
function del() {
    mv $* ~/.Trash
}
```

which just moves your files and folders to the trash such that you can recover them later.

**What’s your choice?**

Comment: Your function will fail when `~/.Trash` is missing. Add `mkdir -p ~ /.Trash` and use `"$@"` instead of unqoted `$*`.

Comment: You should probably use https://askubuntu.com/questions/213533/command-to-move-a-file-to-trash-via-terminal to use the "real" Trash mechanism instead of maintaining your own temporary folders.

Answer (score 1):

You're on a good path if you want to learn how to solve this problem yourself.  However, this is a common problem, and there is already a tool available.

You can install `trash` via `apt install trash-cli`.  Once installed, you can 'safely' delete files, list the contents of Trash, restore files and empty the Trash:

1. `trash /path/to/some/file`
2. `trash-list`
3. `trash-restore`
4. `trash-empty`.

You can read more about [`trash`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/trash.1.html).

---

**Notes:**

1. Some systems will have `restore-trash` instead of `trash-restore`.
2. Many Debian distributions have [`gvfs-trash` from `gvfs-bin` installed by default](https://askubuntu.com/a/525029).
3. [`gvfs-trash` has been replaced by `gio trash`](https://askubuntu.com/a/970504).

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome! You can recover the data almost always (forensic methods). But moving to the trash bin is the fastest and clearest method.