# recover data in linux removed with rm

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, data-loss

Today i deleted my home directory (in wrong action) with:

```
sudo rm -rf *
```

And when i use extundelete i get this message:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo extundelete --restore-directory /home/hamed/ /dev/sda2WARNING: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 746 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 29931 descriptors loaded.
Searching for recoverable inodes in directory /home/hamed/ ... 
498 recoverable inodes found.
Looking through the directory structure for deleted files ... 
498 recoverable inodes still lost.
No files were undeleted.
```

why it can't recover?

Anyone can help me to return my Desktop, Documents and etc?
I have ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't dealt with this myself but have a look here:

[Can files/directories deleted with rm be restored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-from-terminal-be-restored)

Unfortunately rm doesn't move files to trash.

I suspect that extundelete may work but it's going to require some serious reading of the docs.  Enter in terminal:

man extundelete

Good luck.  Hopefully someone else has more positive answers.