# Recover deleted folder in encrypted home

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs

I have a big problem! i accentually deleted a very imported folder in my home dir while creating a backup. I stopped the backup, shutdown the laptop, but there are still a lot of files to be backed up. So I am afraid of manipulating the encrypted home.

The home is encrypted via `ecryptfs` and the system Ubuntu 13.04.

I tried to use `extundelete` from a live usb stick. For the recovery the partition has to be unmounted but then home is encrypted and a recovery of the Document folder is not possible.

Can anybody give my an advise to to recover a folder inside the encrypted home?

The data is very imported because containing a dairy.

Comment: You should stop working on that volume immediately. Unmount or `mount -o ro` it. Do the recovery from a live system if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that you need to unmount the `ecryptfs`-encrypted file system. `ecryptfs` works on top of an underlying file system whereas undeletion tools like `extundelete` operate on ext file systems like the one you probably have underneath your `ecryptfs` file system.

You don't need access to the unencrypted document files to undelete them. Instead you'll undelete the encrypted files in `~/.Private` or wherever your `ecryptfs` file system is located (not mounted).

For the actual undeletion procedure refer to other answers like:

- [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/a/425091/175814)
- [Retrieve files deleted by command rm in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/265992/175814)

Comment: Recovery is often difficult at best and encryption will make it more difficult.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer. I do not think your suggestion is going to easily work due to encryption.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recover a deleted file from my ecryptfs encrypted home folder using `photorec`. This resulted in a large number of files that looked like `f20747184.eCryptfs` in `recup_dir.*` directories.

I moved them all to their own directory.

```
mkdir -p crypted

mv recup_dir.*/*.eCryptfs crypted
```

I recovered my mount password.

```
sudo ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
```

I mounted the crypted directory.

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private crypted/
```

This successfully mounted into a `/tmp/ecryptfs.*/` directory. The filenames are not helpful so I grepped for a keyword that I knew was in the file.

```
grep -R "technology" /tmp/ecryptfs.*
```

I found the file and moved it back.

I know this is an old thread, but this was the first page I found when searching for the solution.