# Restore Direcory/files after rm -rf

Tags: delete, rm

I've accidentally deleted a  project directory from my Ubuntu with rm -rf.

is it possible to restore them somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use data recovery software to try to recover the data from the hard drive. Check out these other similar questions:

- [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)
- [Can files/directories deleted with rm be restored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-with-rm-be-restored)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer that contains only  links to other Ask Ubuntu posts, you should have flagged this question as duplicate of the other ones.