# External Hard Drive Restore

Tags: restore

Installing Ubuntu into my PC, apparently, it got installed into my external hard drive too. When I open my external hard drive, none of the file in it are the original ones but, the ones that I see now are Ubuntu related files. Now, here is the question: can I restore my original external drive's files?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to restore(system files, your pictures, music, etc.), but I'll just give a solution.

[R-Linux](http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/) is a free file recovery utility used in the Linux OS and several Unixes. It has very good [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) from what I gather.

Other info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-with-rm-be-restored).

Comment: It is an external hard drive containing movies, pictures, documents, etc.

Comment: Since Ubuntu is installed, does it boot? If it does, use R-Linux to restore your movies, pictures, etc.