# Restore files deleted by renaming in the terminal

Tags: command-line, data-recovery

After running the following code in a directory (actually a sub-directory of my pictures folder, if that helps) consisting of nothing other than about 60 png images:

```bsh
for i in *;
do  mv "${i}" Surv${53+count}.`echo "${i}" | awk -F. '{print $2}'`;
((++count)); done
```

I found that all but the last of these pngs images had vanished. Is there any way to restore them? At the time I thought that I had them backed up, but I am sad to discover that I have in fact not.

Comment: I can nothing but recommend `alias mv='mv -i'` for the `~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: And what is that, exactly?

Comment: That enables the `-i` option for every time you rename something with `mv` something, so that it asks you for every single file it overwrites. As to your current problem please try the solutions presented in the following question:

Comment: Is this question not more specific than that issue? At the very least, I'd hope that this specific method of deletion would allow for an easier solution.

Comment: You mean more like [Can files/directories deleted with rm be restored?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6698/507051)? I fear there's not much of a difference whether you “deleted” a file with `rm` or “overwrote” it with `mv`, in either case *the link* to the file is destroyed. Recovery tools in general try their best to get these links back, and that's also what you want to do now – as far as I know.