# How to restore Plesk on Ubuntu after accidentally deleted root files (-rm --recursive)

Tags: bash, ssh, restore

I am currently using Plesk on Ubuntu. It is a VPS from AWS Lightsail. 
When I used the SSH, I accidentally recursively removed "/" 
( rm -recursive / )

As I realized I removed the root, I stopped the proccess but it's too late as some of the folders have ben deleted.

I run plesk 12 with all managed websites and domains for my projects. 
now all domains are no longer accessible or cannot be reached.

I have a snapshot backup from several months ago, which is too old for a backup.

My question is, Is there anyway to restore the Ubuntu to certain point? 
I am still having access to SSH so, it might be helpful.

Thank you, I hope someone can give me clue for a reckless and amateur like me :/ 
or, kindly refer me to other channel if this is not a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this issue (Can files/directories deleted with rm be restored?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-with-rm-be-restored):

> Deleting it from terminal deletes it permanently - recovery is very hard and sometimes impossible.

However there are some tools that might help you recover some of your lost data like [Test Disk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), [Foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) or [Extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).

[Testdisk StepByStep](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

[Foremost StepByStep](https://www.howtoforge.com/recover-deleted-files-with-foremost)

[Help with Extundelete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122305/undelete-a-just-deleted-file-on-ext4-with-extundelete)

Also it might be worth to take a look at [Plesk Backup and Resoring](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/reseller-guide/backing-up-and-restoring-data.59744/)